# Show that an open linear mapping between normed spaces is surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'd just like to know where to begin. The exact thing to prove: Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and $R:X\to Y$ is an open linear mapping. Show that $R$ is surjective. And to be clear, neither of the assumed normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ are known to be Banach, and they can be infinite-dimensional spaces too.

Comment: HINT: the unique open supspace of $Y$ is $Y$ itself. Now, $R(X)$ is open (by openness of $R$), and is a subspace (by linearity of $R$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $R$ is open, $R(B_X(0,1))$ contains $B_Y(0,r), r>0$, this implies that $R(B_X(0,n))$ contains $B_Y(0,nr)$. Then use the fact that $\cup_nB_Y(0,nr)=Y$.